# Single User Can't Access RDP by DNS, only by IP

Tags: domain-controller, remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2022

I have three domain controllers, `dc01.ad.exmaple.com` (`10.83.78.10`), `dc02.ad.example.com` (`10.23.20.15`) and `dc03.ad.example.com` (`10.24.20.15`). They are all in the standard Domain Controllers OU.
dc01 is a physical machine running Windows Server 2019. `dc02` and `dc03` are Azure Virtual Machines running Windows Server 2022, `dc02` in `East`, `dc03` in `East 2`.
All the machines are on a VPN and replication is working.

I also have three users in the `Domain Admins` group: `user1.admin`, `user2.admin` and `user3.admin`.

`user1.admin` can not connect to RDP on `dc02` by name, only by IP address. When connecting by hostname, the user gets the message "The logon attempt failed" and nothing is logged anywhere that I could find in Event Viewer. The other users can connect to RDP with no problem using the hostname. If `user1.admin` tries to connect with the IP address instead of the hostname, everything works fine.
[image: Logon error message]

Where else can I look?